# Razor View Engine : An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-4.0, razor

I have a model similar to this:

```
public class SampleModel
{
     public Product Product { get; set; } 
}
```

And in my controller I get an exception trying to print out

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Product.Name)
```

This is the error:

```
Exception: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation
```

If anyone can give me some clues on how to fix this I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Is this on MVC3 RC?  Also can you show us what Product looks like?  I was unable to reproduce it in MVC3 RC

Answer (score 326, accepted):

It seems to me that you have an untyped view. By default, Razor views in MVC3 RC are typed as `dynamic`. However, lambdas do not support dynamic members. You have to strongly type your model. At the top of your view file add

```
@model SampleModel
```

Comment: it was an uppercase m that did it for me

Comment: what if you dot have a model ?

Comment: There should be an option of upvoting twice too, at least after one year. Because your answer again solved my issue.

Answer (score 109):

A common error that is the cause of this is when you add

```
@Model SampleModel
```

at the top of the page instead of

```
@model SampleModel
```

Comment: Thanks for appending this answer! Amazing how after years of programming you can forget about case sensitivity.

Comment: Also can happen if you use "model" instead of "@Model" ... which will build but fail at runtime.

Answer (score 10):

In this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7562489/1535626) explain about @model, see a excerpt:

> `@model` (lowercase "m") is a reserved keyword in Razor views to
>   declare the model type at the top of your view. You have put the
>   namespace too, e.g.: `@model MyNamespace.Models.MyModel`
>
> Later in the file, you can reference the attribute you want with
>   `@Model.Attribute` (uppercase "M").

Comment: This was my problem. If you're not watching carefully, Visual Studio tends to convert what you're typing into the capital "M". It's really irritating.

Answer (score 8):

Before using (strongly type html helper into view) this line

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(p => p.Product.Name)
```

You should include your model into you page for making strongly type view.

```
@model SampleModel
```

Answer (score 7):

Seems like your view is typed `dynamic`. Set the right type on the view and you'll see the error go away.

Answer (score 2):

This error happened to me because I had @@model instead of @model... copy & paste error in my case.  Changing to @model fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

On vb.net you must write @ModelType.