# MVC - Can I set a model attribute in the view and get the value form a script?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is the Controller that returns the above-mentioned view:

```
    public PartialViewResult Day()
    {
        Day model = new Day();
        return PartialView("_Day", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Day(Day model)
    {
        return PartialView("_Day", model);
    }
```

I wrote both the Get and the Post method after I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562393/how-to-set-model-attribute-in-razor-view) question. Note that I haven't set the model in the Controller.

Then I have my View:

```
@model Timing.Models.Day

@{
    Timing.Models.Day d = new Timing.Models.Day();
    d.UserId = "some value";
}
```

This piece of code is working fine: when I go to retrieve, or display, `d.UserId` I get the right value.
Furthermore I have a script in the same view.

```
<script>
    function getUserId() {
        //some code that gets a string
        return userId;
    }
</script>
```

And also this script is working right.
I looked for a solution and this is the best I've been able to find:

```
@{
    Timing.Models.Day d = new Timing.Models.Day();
    d.UserId = Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Getuser", "getUserId()", true);
}
```

But it's not working because of something that is `null` (I wasn't able to understand what was null though).
Is there a way to solve this problem?

For those who ask, I'm using a script because the value I want to set is the one of an html element (this is my related question).
Thanks!

Comment: not clear question ... you want your model's property updated from client side script right?

Comment: It's quite what I'd like to obtain

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declare your variable you want in javascript

```
@{
  var useridForjs = model.property // access model and set useridForjs 
}
```

to use in javascript

```
<script>
function getUserId() {
    //some code that gets a string

  var myserversidevarvalue = '@useridForjs'; // here myserversidevarvalue will store value..
    return userId;
}
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible, ie, to do the opposite process? I mean, if in the script function I write `'@Model.property' = "somevalue";` (maybe in the document ready function) does the View recognize that property with that value?

Comment: but if you want to store only id then do in some hidden variable and then grab data at post time from that hidden variable using request form parameters

Answer (score 0):

Make it easy on yourself and inject your id into a hidden form field, easily obtainable by javascript. Add this to your view:

```
 Html.HiddenFor(model.userId)
```

Then access it like this:

```
 function getUserId() {
    return $('#userId').val();
}
```