# How do I get to the properties of the view model in the view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I need to access the properties of the view model inside the view because I need to assign a value to something in razor but every time I type Model. It doesn't show let me put the properties next it errors.

Here is my code:

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<New_MinecraftNews_Webiste_MVC.Models.ArticlesViewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = Model.Images;
}

<h2>@Model.SelectedArticleType</h2>
```

the `@Model.SelectedArticleType` and `ViewBag.Title = Model.Images;` errors.

The error is:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error CS1061  `IPagedList<ArticlesViewModel>` does not contain a
>   definition for 'Images' and no extension method 'Images' accepting a
>   first argument of type `IPagedList<ArticlesViewModel>` could be found
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my controller:

```
[Route("Articles/{at}")]
public ActionResult ArticleTypes(string at, int page = 1, int pageSize = 15)
{

    articleViewModel.Images = new List<ImageInfo>();
    var modelList = (from a in db.Articles
                     where a.SelectedArticleType == at
                     orderby a.Id descending
                     select new ArticlesViewModel
                     {
                         Id = a.Id,
                         Body = a.Body,
                         Headline = a.Headline,
                         PostedDate = a.PostedDate,
                         SelectedArticleType = a.SelectedArticleType,
                         UserName = a.UserName
                     }).ToList();


    foreach (var item in modelList)
    {
       item.Images = imageService.GetImagesForArticle(item.Id);
    }

    PagedList<ArticlesViewModel> model = new PagedList<ArticlesViewModel>(modelList, page, pageSize);


    return View(model);
}
```

Viewmodel looks like :

```
public class ArticlesViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public List<SelectListItem> ArticleType { get; set; }


    public string SelectedArticleType { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Headline { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime PostedDate { get; set; }

    public ImageInfo MainImage { get; set; }

    public List<ImageInfo> Images { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What exact error do you get? What do your controller action and view models look like?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562393/how-to-set-model-attribute-in-razor-view

Comment: Make sure you are passing a value inside your Model or Model itself to your view. It would be better to see the code inside your controller as well.

Comment: @RustamUmarov controller is there now

Comment: works when i do displayfor and in a foreach loop

Comment: the model in the view is a `PagedList`. is the view suppose to target a collection or a single object?

Comment: a list of article view model

Comment: And what are you trying to do. because the properties you are trying to access are for items in the list not properties on the list itself

Comment: no  there not items in a list sorry they are properties

Comment: @Kyle since your model has various attributes, e.g. Id, Body, Headline, just iterate them in the View and also the better option would be to remove Database Queries to a separate back-end logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<New_MinecraftNews_Webiste_MVC.Models.ArticlesViewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Page title goes here";
}

@foreach (var article in Model) {

    <h1>@article.Headline</h1>
    <h2>@article.SelectedArticleType</h2>

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Reference the PagedList object and not the interface

```
@model PagedList<New_MinecraftNews_Webiste_MVC.Models.ArticlesViewModel>
@using PagedList.Mvc;
@using PagedList;
```

PagedList is a list. So you have to access the child items

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
 {
     @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => Model[i].SelectedArticleType)

 }
```

If you need some 'header' type info on the page and a list associated with that header info, you will probably need to create a partial view for the list and pass the list in via a property on the header info class.