# Issue with MVC combo box -- An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm getting the following error:

*An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation*

Here are the models:

```
public class ProjectType
{
    public string Project { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Server { get; set; }
}

public class ProjectTypesViewModel
{
    public int SelectedId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProjectType> ProjectTypes { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the view:

```
@using BankruptcyDocketGenerator.ViewModels

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Bankruptcy Docket Generator";
}

@{
    ProjectTypesViewModel projectTypes = (ProjectTypesViewModel)ViewBag.ProjectTypes;
}

@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedId, new SelectList(projectTypes.ProjectTypes, "Project", "Name"), "Select one...")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Jay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the following answer, seem that you need to have your view strongly typed in order to work with lambda expressions. Since you are using `@Html.DropDownListFor`, you are using lambda expressions:

[Razor View Engine : An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155392/razor-view-engine-an-expression-tree-may-not-contain-a-dynamic-operation?rq=1)

**Solution:**

Add the following to the top of your view:

```
@model BankruptcyDocketGenerator.ViewModels.ProjectTypesViewModel
```

Update the controller to pass in the ViewModel to the view instead of setting it to the ViewBag:

```
return View(myProjectTypesVm);
```

Comment: Huh. That seems strange to me. I did what you said (and it worked), but I'm still passing the exact same thing into "DropDownListFor". Can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: If you don't type your view, then the view will use `dynamic` as the "type". If you do this, then you cannot use lambda expressions, which is what is used in `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => ...)`