# How to generate crud controller in asp.net mvc using MySql database?

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc, html, entity-framework-4

I try to create a crud controller with asp.net mvc using Mysql database, the database is secure (I can only display tables).

When I try to generate the controller this error appears:

[image: Error Picture Here]

Comment: What Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: visual studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try the following:

- Make sure you have the latest updates for your Visual Studio
- Upgrade to Entity Framework 6 (If you can)
- Modify the context configuration to use IDbSet<...> instead of DbSet<...>

Alternatively, you can also give the below commands a try in the Package Manager Console.

> Uninstall-Package EntityFramework -Force
>
> Install-Package EntityFramework
>
> Uninstall-Package  MvcScaffolding
>
> Install-Package MvcScaffolding

Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23910162/scaffolding-controller-doesnt-work-with-visual-studio-2013-update-2) link for more suggestions.

Comment: Assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework' with identity 'Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' uses 'EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' which has a higher version than referenced assembly 'EntityFramework' with identity 'EntityFramework, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089' NewProject

Comment: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation NewProject

Comment: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation NewProject. This error is not at all related to the issue you posted in your original question. Here is a link to help you with the above mentioned issues.  Someitmes, I little bit of "Google" can help you a lot, instead of just pasting your problems here on Stackoverflow. Check out this link to help you with above error:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155392/razor-view-engine-an-expression-tree-may-not-contain-a-dynamic-operation

Comment: my app was good before using your answer. now i have more than 6 error, thanks for make it worst.