# Display all the contents in the Database Table in a html page?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I need to display all the records in my database to the HTML page.

```
@model QBKartMVC.Models.Products

@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                 <tr>    
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ProductCode)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ProductName)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ProductDes)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ActiveFlag)</td>
                    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Price)</td>
                 </tr>
             }
```

> An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation is the error showing

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var context = new DBContext();
            return View(context.Products.ToList());
        }
```

This is the Controller part

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation is the error showing

Comment: Maybe the error is in the controller. Can you show the code from the controller? Specially where the query is created.

Comment: updated the controller section

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Razor View Engine : An expression tree may not contain a dynamic operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4155392/razor-view-engine-an-expression-tree-may-not-contain-a-dynamic-operation)

Answer (score 0):

Update your view code as below,

```
@model List<QBKartMVC.Models.Products>


@for (var i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
{
     <tr>    
       <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].ProductCode)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].ProductName)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].ProductDes)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].ActiveFlag)</td>
       <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x[i].Price)</td>
     </tr>
}
```

Comment: You have to pass list of products  from controller

Answer (score 0):

you must create IEnumerable List ,like this

```
@model IEnumerable<QBKartMVC.Models.Products>

       @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
             <tr>    
                <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ProductCode)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ProductName)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ProductDes)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.ActiveFlag)</td>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Price)</td>
             </tr>
         }
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
@model List<QBKartMVC.Models.Products>

@foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                 <tr>    
                    <td><input type="checkbox"></td>
                    <td>item.ProductCode</td>
                    <td>item.ProductName</td>
                    <td>item.ProductDes</td>
                    <td>item.ActiveFlag</td>
                    <td>item.Price</td>
                 </tr>
             }
```